# Android map pin move position during zoom in / zoom out

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

In my android app, I have added google map and I load dynamically more points using specific lat / long values and specific pins

This is my code:

```
GoogleMap map = holder.mapView.getMap();
            if(map != null)
            {
                try {
                     MapsInitializer.initialize(activity);
                } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                }
                map.clear();
                map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                LatLng latLng=new LatLng(gS.getLat(), gS.getLon());         
                CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10);
                CameraUpdate center=
                        CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng);
                CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10);
                //map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
                map.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
                map.animateCamera(zoom);
                if(time_diff > day3 && magnitude >= 0 && magnitude < 2)         
                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .draggable(false)
                            .anchor(0, 1)
                            .position(new LatLng(gS.getLat(), gS.getLon()))
                            .title("").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_lt2m)));
```

The code works fine and loads the data into map with custom pin, but I have seen that when I zoom out or zoom in the map, the marker moves its position instead of remaining in its actual lat long position.

Any help?
Thanks

I use API V2. it's possible that a google play service old version create this?

Comment: it's not possible, you do something wrong

Comment: Looks like you use the old api, try samples from the new one https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/

Comment: i use this google play service: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.25'. it's a problem?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup it's `3.2.25` vs. `15.0.1`.